# Remove required field validation of configurable attribute in product view page magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am using **Magento ver. 1.9.0.1.** I just want to **remove the validation of configurable attribute** as it is not necessary to select. If the user will not select the configurable attribute then default product will add to cart.
 I checked all stuffs but didn't get the fruitful result.

Thanks!

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GO to the folder /catalog/product/view/type/option/configurable.phtml and there you have to do hard coding by your self

Comment: yes i tried there. I removed required classes as well then also no use. If you would help me for this then it would be better.

Comment: for that you have to create a simple product same values as configurable product and add to cart that simple product , because you cannot add to cart configurable product directly